# how to declare typescript interface extension to node request session object?

Tags: typescript, passport.js

In the following, `returnTo` is added to the session object by my passport methods.  How do I declare its interface in typescript?

```
import express = require('express');
import expressSession = require('express-session');

// how to declare presence of returnTo, which is not in underlying type?

export function createSession(req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: Function) {

  passport.authenticate('local', (err: any, user: UserInstance, info: any) => {
    //. . .
    req.logIn(user, (err) => {
      //. . .
      res.redirect(req.session.returnTo || '/');
    });
  })(req, res, next);
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a type declaration for `express-session` on DefinitelyTyped:

https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/express-session/express-session.d.ts

Following the pattern in that file, you can create a new `d.ts` (call it whatever you want) containing:

```
declare module Express {
  export interface Session {
    returnTo: string;
  }
}
```

TypeScript will "merge" this extra property into the existing definitions.

Comment: I tried adding this definition into my // comment area above, but still get an error: src/server/controllers/sessionsController.ts(39,32): error TS2339: Property 'returnTo' does not exist on type 'Session'.

Comment: I get it - you have to have this definition in an external file.  That works fine.  Thanks!

Comment: That's right - stuff you declare in a module with exports/imports will not be global, and so won't merge with a pre-existing global declaration.

Answer (score 3):

Just create a generic T and passed instead of request

```
<T extends {session: {user: any}}, Request>(sessionRequest: T) => {}
```