# External file doesn't compile in Typescript

Tags: session, typescript, express-session

I'm using express-session with Typescript and running into the expected issue with the following error message -

Property 'authz' does not exist on type 'Session'

To fix this, I did add a new external file called session.d.ts with the following contents -

```
import { Resources, ResourceAuth, Authz } from "../../models/Authz"

declare namespace Express {
  export interface Session {
    authz: Array<ResourceAuth>;
  }
}
```

and in my controller, I have the following -

`/// <reference path="../../../@types/session/session.d.ts" />`

However, I still keep getting the error. It looks as it my d.ts file is not being picked up. Here's my tsconfig. What am I missing ?

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "build",
    "sourceMap": true,
     "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types",
      "./@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "core-js"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/@types/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do import/export statements in a definition file.

What you actually want to do is to extend the existing interface Session. You can do this with interface merging in a normal *.ts-file/module described here:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html

However, since the interface you are trying to extend is in a different namespace, this is not going to work. I have the same problem and asked it here:
[Typescript: How to extend an existing interface in a globally declared namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41101727/typescript-how-to-extend-an-existing-interface-in-a-globally-declared-namespace)

Since you want a solution: What I usually do is casting to any and then accessing the value, cause I know it's there:

```
let mySession: express.Session = session;
let authz = (<any>mySession).authz;
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. However, I'm hoping there's a better solution than to use <any>, otherwise I'd rather just use Javascript.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31304438/how-to-declare-typescript-interface-extension-to-node-request-session-object/41115298#41115298 seems to discuss a similar problem and the poster was able to extend it. Not sure what the difference is.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that if I use the array notation, it just works fine.

So session['anythingreally'] = Authz.getAuthz() works!