# Typescript: How to extend an existing interface in a globally declared namespace

Tags: typescript, kendo-ui

I'm trying to extend an existing interface of KendoUI which comes from a definition file.
With interface merging this is normally straight forward but the interface I'm going to extend is in a specific global namespace "kendo.ui"

I'm ust trying to add "hideInEditor" propterty to the interface to the kendo.ui.GridColumn interface like this.

```
namespace kendo.ui {
    export interface GridColumn {
        hideInEditor?: boolean;
    }   
}
```

However, the compiler seems to have forgotten all about the orginal definitions and I can no longer access the kendo namespace as all types are missing. So apparently this is wrong. But what is the correct way to extend such an interface?

Comment: Can you show how you import/reference the kendo-ui lib?

Comment: It is s global "namespace". I just supply the global declarations and import the javascript library like this   <script src="Scripts/kendo/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

Comment: How do you "supply the global declarations"?

Comment: By having the kendo.ui.d.ts definitions file in my scripts folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the type definition files in the same folder doesn't do anything unless you somehow tell the compiler to look for them.

In your case I think you need this:

```
/// <reference path="./kendo.ui.d.ts" />

namespace kendo.ui {
    export interface GridColumn {
        hideInEditor?: boolean;
    }
}

let obj: kendo.ui.GridColumn;
console.log(kendo.culture()); // ok
console.log(obj.format); // ok
console.log(obj.hideInEditor); // ok
```

Note the first line with the `reference`.

Comment: Thanks this seems to work. Kendo still wont accept it, but I'm starting to think this might be related to something else.