# Can I override tilde-slash in Razor v2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Razor view engine [supports tilde-slash](http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/asp.net-mvc-4-the-new-tilde-slash-feature-in-razor-2) paths out of the box like this:

```
<script src="~/js/myscript.js" /> <!-- cool trick by the way!! -->
```

Is there any way I can override the processing of tilde?

**Reason behind this**

The reason I want to "override" this is because I use a CDN so the "root" should point to a different domain.

I already wrote my own replacement for `Url.Content("~/blahblah")` extension so it points where I need it to (my own `Url.ContentCDN("~/blah")` actually points to `xxx.cloudfront.net/blah`) can I do something like this for Razor's built-in "hack"? Not sure where do I start...

Or the only way would be to find all the tilde-paths in my solution and plug my Url-extension? (the solution is quite big, hundreds of views, so a "cleaner" way would be to overload/override this)

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to declare typescript interface extension to node request session object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31304438/how-to-declare-typescript-interface-extension-to-node-request-session-object)