# In TypeScript, how can I resolve 'Property does not exist on type'?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have just upgraded Node.js from v 6 (previously working) to v 8 (not working).

I have a line of code where I try to preserve the path the user is trying to access:

```
req.session.returnTo = req.path;
```

Since the upgrade, I am getting:

```
error TS2339: Property 'returnTo' does not exist on type 'Session'
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Could be a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31304438/how-to-declare-typescript-interface-extension-to-node-request-session-object

Comment: It's unlikely this has something to do with Node version. More like it's typing version or anything else in your project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to declare typescript interface extension to node request session object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31304438/how-to-declare-typescript-interface-extension-to-node-request-session-object)